# Where to purchase multitrack music loops?

Tags: audio, music

I've seen other questions about where to find royalty-free music available for purchase. But most of these tend to provide a single audio file with every instrument track already blended and mixed together. I'm more interested in the dynamic music route, and would want to download a bundle of audio files (one for bass, one for kick, etc) and in my game I can just bring them in and out based off of what's going on. When things are quiet just have the bass line repeating and when things get chaotic the full piece is going. Obviously each track would need to be on the same beat and designed to work well with each other part. Is there any place that such multitrack loops could purchased? Thanks.

Comment: Would this be considered off-topic?

Comment: Unfortunately our Q&A format isn't well-suited to requests for external resources. They tend to attract lists of answers with no clear "correct" solution, and the answers age poorly as links rot or newer resources become available, leaving the Q&A thread misleading for future readers. This type of question is often better to ask on the GameDev.net forums or in [chat] if your own searching hasn't turned up any leads.

Comment: http://www.IndieGameMusic.com has a few of those. They're called "Building blocks". Not too many of them though.